# How to write list of strings to Amazon s3 files using Java

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, coding-style

I have to write the List of strings as rows in an Amazon S3 file. For example:

> List {str1,st2, str3}

will get converted into file having lines as

```
str1
str2
str3
```

I have one approach to do this, i.e covert this list as a string separated with "\n" and write this string to s3.
ex

```
 String s3Strinng =  String.join("\n",
                        myList
                        .stream()
                        .collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

Is there any other way to do this in bettter way in java?
Any code pointers will help a ton.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not just String.join("\n", myList) ?

Comment: Yeah I can do it, My main concern is about combining them with "\n" is it a good practice

Comment: It is. I don’t know of any alternative anyway

Answer (score 2):

Your logic looks fine. Once you get the String value, you can place the content into an Amazon S3 bucket by using the Amazon S3 API. Invoke the **S3Client** object's **putObject** method.

```
PutObjectRequest putOb = PutObjectRequest.builder()
                    .bucket(bucketName)
                    .key(objectKey)
                    .build();

PutObjectResponse response = s3.putObject(putOb,
                    RequestBody.fromString(<YOUR String>);
```

Notice **RequestBody** has this method:

https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/core/sync/RequestBody.html#fromString-java.lang.String-